# Баг IE: контейнер заканчивается раньше дочернего центровщика

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Очень трудно было выбрать тему для данного вопроса: "У меня не так отображается, помогите!" - это не тема, но дело в том, что в данном вопросе рассматривается очередной баг Internet Explorer (то есть в других браузерах всё отображается нормально), причину которого никак не удаётся выяснить.

К задаче. У нас типичный блок `.Wrapper`, который имеет ширину 100% от окна, и центровщик (`margin: 0 auto;`) с указанными `min-width` и `max-width`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В IE следующий баг: `Wrapper` почему-то заканчивается раньше, чем надо, а центровщик с содержимым перекрывает следующую такую же компоновку ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой баг был замечен уже практически на свёрстанном лендинге, а потому было очень трудно сделать минимальный работающий пример. Я постарался убрать весь лишний HTML для данного примера, но CSS тоже самое было сделать очень трудно.

Если Вы запустите [пример](https://jsfiddle.net/r6v7emv2/) в IE (ещё раз повторюсь, что в других браузерах всё нормально), то увидите следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Расскажу о том, что обнаружил сам. Сама по себе верхняя компоновка Wrapper-Centerer-Содержимое отображается корректно (её содержимое - таблица). Баг появляется при появлении нижней комбинации. Вообще там есть внутренний контейнер с зафлоченными элементами, но всё равно неясно, в чём проблема. Естественно, везде где надо, есть `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: поставь тут `.FlexPageLayoutWithFixedHeaderAndBottomFooter-Wrapper` вместо `height` - `min-height`

Comment: @Grundy, благодарю Вас за ответ. Всё заработало в IE. К сожалению, если задать `min-height: 100vh`, исчезнет прилипание header-а кверху. Из примера я header, естественно, убрал, но вообще он всегда в верхней части `FlexPageLayoutWithFixedHeaderAndBottomFooter-Wrapper`, а всё остальное обёрнуто в другой контейнер, который занимает всё оставшееся пространство от между header-ом и низом экрана (естественно, у этого контейнера есть вертикальная прокрутка).  Таким образом, header у меня всегда в верхней части экрана.

Comment: @Grundy, Во-первых, я прошу Вас объяснить в ответе, почему именно `min-height` решает проблему в IE. И второе: если ли какое-нибудь решение с сохранением прилипания header-а кверху без задания его абсолютной высоты?

Comment: про header не понял, ты его в пример можешь добавить?

Comment: @Grundy, [Добавил](https://jsfiddle.net/r6v7emv2/1/). Теперь header всегда вверху.

Comment: Сделайте, пожалуйста, код кодом а не картинкой.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov, Тот код, который на верхней картинке, не есть тот же код, что в JS Fiddle. В некотором роди имитация.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К `section` добавьте `flex: 1 0 auto`:

https://jsfiddle.net/Kniha/mLh63fao/3/

В примере добавлено через `section[class$='-RootWrapper']`.

Comment: Простое решение после стольких усилий! Какое счастье, что я могу отблагодарить Вам чем-то кроме слов, а именно очками репутации.